# Themes: How to change the color settings of a temporary field within the Info panel

Tags: theme

I am modifying the theme of Blender, and have most of the settings where I want them. However, I am having difficulty with a temporary message field, circled in yellow below.

[image: Blender Screenshot]

I have messed around with every possible setting in the Info panel section of the Themes window:

[image: Themes Panel]
...but none of them seem to affect this particular field.

Does anyone know the name of this field, and where I can change the display colors for it? The white text on light grey background is a bit difficult to see, even on my iMac's 5K Retina display.

Also, is there any good reference available where I can see exactly where each item in the Themes panel is used within the Blender interface?

In case you are curious, I am running macOS 10.14 Mojave beta in dark mode with the red accent color, as shown here:
[image: macOS Mojave Display Settings]

Comment: Have you seen a different bg colour for that widget when using another theme?

Comment: Hmmm... That is a good question, and what I found was interesting. I went through every one of the themes, and the background did not change for any of them. However, the text color DID change for a few of them.